# AWS: Start EC2 Instance with Cloudformation and encrypt BlockDevices with specific KMS Key

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-kms

When starting EC2 instances via aws cli I can specify a KmsKeyId for BlockDevices.
When starting an EC2 instance via Cloudformation (either directly or via ASG/LaunchConfiguration) this option does not exist.

How can I encrypt the block devices of my EC2 instances started via Cloudformation with a specific KMS Key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the chain is:

[Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html) > [ [BlockDeviceMapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-blockdev-mapping.html) ] > [Ebs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-blockdev-template.html) > [KmsKeyId](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-blockdev-template.html#cfn-ec2-instance-ebs-kmskeyid)

[image]

Comment: But there is no KmsKeyId in the [Ebs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-blockdev-template.html) Property

Comment: I'm a bit confused. When I follow the [Ebs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-blockdev-template.html) link I do see a `KmsKeyId` proprty. I added a screenshot to show what I see

Comment: Ok, it is missing in the german translation of the documentation ... thanks, I was simply reading an outdated documentation

Comment: Ah interesting, that makes sense now. I added feedback on that German page to let them know.